# Default value for nested variables in jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

This will error if `output` does not exist:

```yaml
result.output == false                 # error: dict has no attribute 'output'
```

So I must use a default:

```yaml
result.output | default(false) == false
```

But how do I deal with non-existent `output` in two levels (a null coalescing problem):

```yaml
result.output.something == false       # error: dict has no attribute 'output'
```

Comment: `result.output.something is not defined or result.output.something == false` should do.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε That worked. If you add that as an answer, I'll close. Thank you!

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Though I used: `result.output is defined and result.output.something |default(false) == false` to check for errors on both levels  (I didn't know jinja2 has short-circuit evaluation, thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified version of @β.εηοιτ.βε's comment above:

```yaml
result.output is defined
and result.output.something |default(false) == false
```